# No "Install Ubuntu" option when booting from USB drive

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, windows-10, secure-boot

I decided to install Ubuntu on my laptop alongside Windows 10. I downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 iso file from the official Ubuntu website. I formatted my USB from NTFS to FAT32 and used Rufus 3.12 to make a bootable USB drive with the Ubuntu .iso file that I had downloaded.

After getting into the BIOS I selected the boot from USB in the boot menu, but I didn't get any "Install Ubuntu" option. It seemed to me as if Ubuntu has already been installed, but it hasn't. I also tried Universal USB Installer 19.9.5 instead of Rufus, but the result was same.

This is the next screen after I chose booting from USB in the boot menu.

[image]

These are the errors I got after choosing the first "Ubuntu" option.

[image: These are the errors I got after choosing the first "Ubuntu" option]

```
Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Comment: Did you disable `Secure Boot` in the BIOS/UEFI ?

Comment: Yes, but didn't help

Comment: What machine is it?

Comment: It is Asus x571gt-bq103t.

Comment: You also have to make sure that Windows fast startup is disabled.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://www.pcsteps.com/3305-prepare-windows-dual-boot-installation/) and its [follow-up](https://www.pcsteps.com/961-install-ubuntu-linux-windows/). Don't worry that he mentions Ubuntu 17, it's the same for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I turned off the Windows fast startup and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case is

1. to make sure that `Secure Boot` is disabled in the BIOS/UEFI and
2. Disable Windows fast startup (Win 8.1 and Win 10). This is done by booting into Windows, and calling up the Settings menu and looking for "Turn on fast startup", then uncheck it.