# No "install Ubuntu" option when booting from USB

Tags: system-installation, usb, 20.04, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to my laptop, but I ran into similar problem as the one from this link:
[No "Install Ubuntu" option when booting from USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286777/no-install-ubuntu-option-when-booting-from-usb-drive/1302046#1302046)
I tried the solution from that page but it didn't work. And I just can't seems to find a solution for this. My laptop is Asus a455l. Sorry for the repeated question and thanks for the help in advance.
[image: .]

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the option to install Ubuntu? It’s generally done from the live environment if you’re installing Ubuntu Desktop. [This walk-through from Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) has a pretty decent set of instructions to follow.

Comment: Yes, I'm following the steps provided by Canonical, but when I tried to boot my usb from bios setting, instead of showing the welcome window like the one from the walk-through, it instead shows the GNU Grub with the options like in the link I provided earlier. there is no option to install Ubuntu. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Here's what I did:

1. When in BIOS settings I enabled CSM.
2. Then I restart my laptop and open BIOS settings again.
3. Now there are several new boot options:

   - [UEFI] USB drive name
   - ...
   - USB drive name <------- I chose this, and ubuntu finally loaded

I hope my experience is any help for some people. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you managed to work it out. Hopefully this helps other people who use an Asus A455L as well 