# Trying install Ubuntu 21.10 on an empty x86-64 I don't get an install option

Tags: grub2, system-installation

A grub menu appears with the option to run ubuntu not install it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. Explain what you are doing. Are you trying to boot from a LiveUSB?

Comment: I think that this might be a graphics thing and the install graphics is not working with my nvidia card so I get taken to the try ubuntu option instead.

Comment: I am not trying to use a live db I am trying to install Ubuntu on a fresh box but I do not get the graphical interface just a grub screen

Comment: So select "Try Ubuntu", then boot into it, and there will be an install option.

Comment: I don't want to try it I want  to install it.

Comment: There is no such option only a grub screen not graphical stuff.

Comment: So select "Ubuntu" in the grub. What happens next?

Comment: I have the standard install cd and I am booting from it to install ubuntu but getting no option to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130733/discussion-between-pilot6-and-matthew-v-carey).

Comment: It does a lot of wirring and I get the normal booting ubuntu commands creeping by if I press esc. It tries to boot ubuntu from the cd and finds it can't do a lot. I want install it. I did the same thing a year ago and it was dead easy.

Comment: It is now dead easy too. Just let the system boot. It may take some time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No "install Ubuntu" option when booting from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302060/no-install-ubuntu-option-when-booting-from-usb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So run Ubuntu and after you boot into it, you'll have the install option.