# no install ubuntu option when booting from a usb alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, windows-10

I have tried the solutions to the same problem
in [No "Install Ubuntu" option when booting from USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286777/no-install-ubuntu-option-when-booting-from-usb-drive) but it has not worked. I am trying to install ubuntu on my desktop, it has an ssd, gpt and uefi. There also is no option to enable csm.

Comment: CSM **should** be disabled. How did you made the installation/live USB? What options do you have in the Grub menu?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the guided "Install Alongside Windows" option, a few conditions must be met:

- You need enough **unpartitioned free space** to install Ubuntu. The minimum recommended space for Ubuntu Desktop is 25 GB, but it is generally wise to allocate more space because running out of space on your root filesystem can be catastrophic. Do not create any partitions or file systems ahead of time. Consult Windows documentation if you need to shrink your Windows partition to free up unpartitioned free space for Ubuntu.
- You must boot the USB installation media in the same mode that Windows is already installed. So if Windows is a UEFI installation, you need to boot the Ubuntu installation media as UEFI, not BIOS or "legacy" or "compatibility".
- Windows must be fully shut down. If you are using "Fast Startup" in Windows, disable it, because Fast Startup is a hybrid suspend and prevents the system from fully shutting down.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have partitioned 300GB of space. I have booted the USB in UEFI using GPT which is the mode of the windows. I also disabled “Fast Startup” and shut the down windows. However I still don’t get the install Ubuntu option. I followed the instructions from the canonical Ubuntu tutorial to create the live USB

Comment: There can not be a partition where you want to install Ubuntu. It must be unpartitioned free space.  Also, are you absolutely sure that Windows is UEFI?