# No 'install ubuntu' option when booting from live USB

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, system-installation, live-usb

I wanted to re-install Ubuntu (dual boot with Win10) to have it on a larger partition (ran out of space beforehand). To do this, I have changed the boot order to have it boot directly to Win10, and then I deleted and merged the partition with the Win10 partition. I have also deleted the ubuntu boot folder via Diskpart (as explained [here](https://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/)).

Then, I created a new (larger, 100GB) partition and created a live USB with the latest 20.04 release from the Ubuntu website, but when I boot from this USB I do not get the 'install ubuntu' option. The only options are (similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286777/no-install-ubuntu-option-when-booting-from-usb-drive)):

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu (safe graphics)
- OEM install (for manufacturers)
- Boot from next volume
- UEFI firmware settings

So, the things I have tried didn't work, and I was curious if anyone here has another suggestion as to what may help me install my dual boot. Things I tried:

- Disabled secure boot
- Disabled fast startup
- Tried creating live USB with Rufus and Universal USB Installer
- Tried all options, the first three give me a black screen and the fourth boots to Win10, fifth goes to UEFI
- Tried to manually boot into the three available EFI files on the live USB (BOOTx64.efi, grubx64.efi, mmx64.efi)
- Looked for booting in legacy mode (as suggested [here](https://ubuntu.forumming.com/question/15874/no-ldquo-install-ubuntu-rdquo-option-when-booting-from-usb)) but my UEFI doesn't show this option

Additionally, in the UEFI the only option it gives next to the Windows Bootloader is booting from the USB itself, which usually should get me to the 'install Ubuntu' option.

I have no idea what to try next, but my friend suggested that somehow the USB may think that a version of Ubuntu is still installed (maybe some remnants from the deleted install?), and will therefore try to boot it but can't find it, hence the black screen. Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Laptop is an Asus ZenBook Flip 15.

Comment: Try selecting "Ubuntu" -- the first boot option.  And when you're logged in, "Install Ubuntu" should be an option that appears on the desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I select the first boot option, I get a black screen and nothing happens. I can't log in this way unfortunately...

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, I don't think that it's booting into the "remnants" of a deleted installation.  You can try another version of Ubuntu (i.e., 21.10) and see if you still get a black screen.  Or try the USB drive in another computer.  I just tried installing a recent version of Ubuntu and I can confirm that the "Install Ubuntu" option appears after you log in, as a program on the desktop.

Comment: I think you are right, I tried it on a friend's computer and got the same GRUB options, however when selecting 'ubuntu' it did boot as you said. This hinted at it being a problem with the computer. I found another askUbuntu question about black screen which led me to the answer. I'll post the complete answer below.

Comment: Good to hear you were able to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

So after some experimentation I figured out the solution. The problem wasn't anything I thought, but when searching for 'black screen after selecting ubuntu in GRUB' I stumbled upon [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138820/black-screen-after-grub-selection-boot-from-usb-live) question and tried it.

What worked for me in the end was booting from USB, and then going to the kernel command line for the 'Ubuntu' option in GRUB (press 'e' when the right option is selected). In this terminal, I changed "`quiet splash`" to "`noacpi acpi=off`" as suggested in the first bullet of the answer I linked.
F10 to boot and it worked.

The 'install ubuntu' option then comes after it has booted.

EDIT1: Did not realise question may not be available in the future, so some context: The question is about installing Ubuntu, but after selecting 'install ubuntu' from GRUB, the screen stays black, similar to what happens when I select 'ubuntu'. The author names a few things they've tried:

> I tried lot of stuff while I was searching for a solution. In UEFI I set SATA to AHCI, turned off Secure Boot and Fast Boot.

> I tried edit the command from GRUB replacing quiet splash with `nomodeset`, `nvidia.modeset=0` or `nouveau.modeset=0`. Nothing helped.

The answer that helped me was what I've described here, but I quote:

> TL;DR - Add "`acpi=off`" to kernel command line.

> The nomodeset option is used for a "safe graphics" install, but maybe your issue isn't related to graphics.

> In the past, I have had success in this situation by trial and error with the following:

> modify kernel cmdline settings, press 'e' at the GRUB menu, and replace "`quiet splash`" (as you have done) with "`noacpi acpi=off`".

EDIT2: I got further with installing it, but near the end of installation, I get an error saying: 'Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda'failed. This is a fatal error.' Did not solve this one yet and am not sure this error is related.

Comment: If there is important info in the other question it needs to be included here. That other question may not exist in the future making your answer useless.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I did not realise the question may not exist in the future. I added some context regarding the linked question now, hopefully making it clearer.